# How to group by DateTime.Date in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a device model:

```
public class DeviceModel
{
    public DateTime Added { get;set; }
}
```

And i want to select devices count, grouped by `Added` date (**not Date and Time, but only date**). My current implementation is not valid, because linq can't translate `DateTime.Date` to sql:

```
var result = (
    from device in DevicesRepository.GetAll()
    group device by new { Date = device.Added.Date } into g
    select new
        {
            Date = g.Key.Date,
            Count = g.Count()
        }
    ).OrderBy(nda => nda.Date);
```

How to change this query to make it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN document, `Date` property is supported by LINQ to SQL and I'd assume that Entity Framework supports it as well.

Anyway, try this query (notice that I'm using [TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method in order to avoid resolving the date repeatedly):

```
var result = from device in
                 (
                     from d in DevicesRepository.GetAll()
                     select new 
                     { 
                         Device = d, 
                         AddedDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.Added) 
                     }
                 )
             orderby device.AddedDate
             group device by device.AddedDate into g
             select new
             {
                 Date = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunallety, Date is not supported in EF6. About EntityFunctions, this class is obsolete, i used DbFunctions instead. But, this solution works. thanks.

Comment: For further readers, the new not depricated method is: `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()` in `using System.Data.Entity;`

Answer (score 1):

Use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime

```
var result = (
from device in DevicesRepository.GetAll()
group device by new { Date = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(device.Added)} into g
select new
    {
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        Count = g.Count()
    }
).OrderBy(nda => nda.Date);
```