# Compare two DateTime variables

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I want to compare two Date Time variables. I have this in code of the old project:

```
 public int GetTotal(DateTime d)
    {
        using (rdbyDataContext2 Context = new rdbyDataContext2())
        {
            var q1 = from qu in Context.SearchRequests
                     where
                       qu.search_date.Year.Equals(d.Year) && qu.search_date.Month.Equals(d.Month) && qu.search_date.Day.Equals(d.Day)  
                     orderby qu.user_name
                     select qu;

            return q1.Count();
        }
    }
```

So, I wanna to compare DateTime variables faster. How may I implement it?

Comment: What's wrong with the current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to compare Date without the time of the day, this should do it :

```
public int GetTotal(DateTime d)
{
    using (rdbyDataContext2 Context = new rdbyDataContext2())
    {
        var q1 = from qu in Context.SearchRequests
                 where
                   qu.search_date.Date = d.Date
                 orderby qu.user_name
                 select qu;
        return q1.Count();
    }
}
```

`DateTime.Date` is correctly handle by LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Now it's working faster in 10 times(with index, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the Date part only (not the Time):

```
qu.search_date.Date == d.Date
```

Comment: Based on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186104/how-to-group-by-datetime-date-in-entityframework) I don't think EF handles `DateTime.Date`, assuming that the OP is using EF.

Comment: In Linq-To-Sql it is supported.

Comment: It's not EF. It's linq-to-Sql