# Parsing Date portion of a DateTime with a BinaryExpression

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I've found answers for a similar concept, but none of them seems to fit my case.

I'm building an object that filters results by a Where clause and a Lambda for types known at runtime.

A filter array can contains one or more filters with a property name, and equality operator (i.e. gte, eq, neq, etc) and the value to compare.

Since I could have more than one property to filter, I first grab all the BinaryExpression that I need to compare any object property 
and merge them in a single expression that gets passed to a query Where clause.

If the filter's property type is a DateTime I want to compare only the Date portion of the property using a BinaryExpression.

I've a method that receives the filter's parameter name and its value.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetEqualExpression<T>(string parameterName,
            string comparisonValue) {

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), parameterName);
    var property = Expression.Property(param, parameterName);

    var propInfo = (PropertyInfo) property.Member;
    var propType = propInfo.PropertyType;

    if (propType == typeof(DateTime)) {

        // Parse the string to a DateTime.
        const string dateFormat = "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K";
        var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(comparisonValue, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

        // Trying to access the 'Date' child property.
        property = Expression.Property(property, "Date");
        var constant = Expression.Constant(parsedDate.Date);


        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(property, constant), param);
    }

    ...
}
```

considering for example an object as:

```
public class Ticket {
    public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime DueDate {get; set;}
}
```

and a filter for the 'StartDate' property, when I pass the expression to the query's where clause, it fails with exception "Lambda parameter not in scope.";

What I'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

## Update

So, thanks to [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos) I've discovered that ServiceStack.OrmLite (the ORM I'm using) doesn't support accessing the Date property, much like EF. So now the question is, How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is how I managed the situation. I'd like to really thanks [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos) to point me out to the DateTime.Date issue with the ORM.

I've decided to compare dates equality by time range in the following manner:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetEqualExpression(string parameterName, 
    string comparisonValue)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), parameterName);
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, parameterName);

    var propInfo = (PropertyInfo) Property.Member;
    var propType = propInfo.PropertyType;

    if (propType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        const string dateFormat = "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K";
        var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(comparisonValue, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var dayStart = new DateTime(parsedDate.Year, parsedDate.Month, parsedDate.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var dayEnd = new DateTime(parsedDate.Year, parsedDate.Month, parsedDate.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);

        var left = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(prop, Expression.Constant(dayStart)), param);
        var right = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.LessThanOrEqual(prop, Expression.Constant(dayEnd)), param);

        return left.Compose(right, Expression.And);
    }

    ...
}
```

This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error: you must use

```
Expression.Equal(property, constant)
```

instead of

```
Expression.Equals(property, constant)
```

And then perhaps you have a problem in the *Since I could have more than one property to filter, I first grab all the BinaryExpression that I need to compare any object property **and merge them in a single expression** that gets passed to a query Where clause* part

Note that if you are using Entity Framework, the `DateTime.Date` is probably not supported. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21186498/613130 . One possible solution is to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, Expression.Equals is a typo, I'm in fact using Expression.Equal. I'm not using EntityFramework but ServiceStack.OrmLite. The expression merge works fine with simple types as string and numbers. I stressed the concept just to specify that I cannot access the property directly. (like in query.Where(q => q.StartDate.Date == parsedDate.Date)

Comment: @RobertoMauro Try checking if you can execute a query with `Date` without using the Expression (so building really a query like `query.Where(q => q.StartDate.Date == someDate.Date)`, just to check that the Orm supports it.

Comment: Yep, you're right, it doesn't support accessing the Date property. I don't why I've taken that for granted. I guess I'm screwed. :\

Comment: @RobertoMauro Normally Orm have "extension points" to connect SQL functions... But I don't use OrmLite, so I don't know how it is done. It is probably better that you ask a totally new question tagged with `ormlite-ServiceStack` or whatever the tag is just about this argument, so that perhaps someone expert in that orm can help you.